# Pipelining bootstrap into my ruby on rails application to style it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, server

I just added the gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.3' into my gemfile pages. I reinstall the bundle as follows (as specified):

```
 Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
    Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
    Resolving dependencies...
Installing rake 10.4.2
Installing i18n 0.7.0
Installing json 1.8.2
Installing minitest 5.5.1
Installing thread_safe 0.3.4
Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
Installing activesupport 4.2.0
Installing builder 3.2.2
Installing erubis 2.7.0
Installing mini_portile 0.6.2
Installing nokogiri 1.6.6.2
Installing rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
Installing rails-dom-testing 1.0.5
Installing loofah 2.0.1
Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.1
Installing actionview 4.2.0
Installing rack 1.6.0
Installing rack-test 0.6.3
Installing actionpack 4.2.0
Installing globalid 0.3.3
Installing activejob 4.2.0
Installing mime-types 2.4.3
Installing mail 2.6.3
Installing actionmailer 4.2.0
Installing activemodel 4.2.0
Installing arel 6.0.0
Installing activerecord 4.2.0
Installing execjs 2.3.0
Installing autoprefixer-rails 5.1.7
Installing debug_inspector 0.0.2
Installing binding_of_caller 0.7.2
Installing sass 3.4.13
Installing bootstrap-sass 3.3.3
Using bundler 1.8.3
Installing columnize 0.9.0
Installing debugger-linecache 1.2.0
Installing slop 3.6.0
Installing byebug 3.5.1
Installing coffee-script-source 1.9.1
Installing coffee-script 2.3.0
Installing thor 0.19.1
Installing railties 4.2.0
Installing coffee-rails 4.1.0
Installing hike 1.2.3
Installing multi_json 1.10.1
Installing jbuilder 2.2.8
Installing jquery-rails 4.0.3
Installing tilt 1.4.1
Installing sprockets 2.12.3
Installing sprockets-rails 2.2.4
Installing rails 4.2.0
Installing rdoc 4.2.0
Installing sass-rails 5.0.1
Installing sdoc 0.4.1
Installing spring 1.3.3
Installing sqlite3 1.3.10
Installing turbolinks 2.5.3
Installing uglifier 2.7.1
Installing web-console 2.1.0
Bundle complete! 14 Gemfile dependencies, 59 gems now installed.
Gems in the group production were not installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
Post-install message from rdoc:
Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:

<= 1.8.6 : unsupported
 = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
 = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
>= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
```

All good till here.

Then i added the code `@import "bootstrap";` into my styles.css.scss file.
I restarted the server for the changes to reflect in localhost:3000
Then this happens:

```
    rails server
Warning: Running `gem pristine --all` to regenerate your installed gemspecs (and deleting then reinstalling your bundle if you use bundle --path) will improve the startup performance of Spring.
Could not find autoprefixer-rails-5.1.7 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I tried running 'bundle install' but to my dismay the same error crept up again and again.
So in a jist, the server doesn't start citing "it couldn't find autoprefixer-rails-5.1.7 gem " but if you check the script above it has actually installed it.

Please help me fix this.

Comment: Could you please provide output of `ps aux | grep ruby` command? Seems like you have running Rails app with Spring.

Comment: prafulk         22466   0.0  0.0  2441988    660 s000  S+    9:42PM   0:00.00 grep ruby

Comment: @maxd Any progress? Please help me out.

Comment: Try to disable `spring` gem and remove related code from `bin/rails`.

Comment: @maxd. I restarted the terminal and tried `rails s` . It worked and the server ran and launched the page. There is a new error that crept up now. Please check it here   [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28816010/i-installed-bootstrap-and-refreshed-the-page-i-received-this-error-sasssynta) .....Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

I ran the command `bundle exec rails s`. The server runs now. But it still isn't running if the command `rails s` is executed. It throws the same error.